# Need help installing rJava on Mac

Tags: r, macos, rjava, xlconnect

I am trying to download the package Xlconnect on my mac but I keep getting errors. I was able to figure out that it was because mac has some issue with Java and that I need to first resolve that before. But I've had no luck so far.

One of the things I tried was this: https://www.chrisjmendez.com/2018/11/16/installing-xlconnect-and-rjava-on-macos/

But it didn't work as well.

Can someone who has been able to successfully install rJava help me out please?

```html
configure: error: One or more Java configuration variables are not set.
Make sure R is configured with full Java support (including JDK). Run
R CMD javareconf
as root to add Java support to R.

If you don't have root privileges, run
R CMD javareconf -e
to set all Java-related variables and then install rJava.

ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rJava’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/47/523c7yns0dvgc2cy147fbxrh0000gn/T/RtmpkLRoEh/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: Did you run `R CMD javareconf` or `R CMD javareconf -e` on the command line as suggested by the error message? Did you restart R afterward?

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.owsiak.org/r4-0-with-java-14-inside-macos-10-15-4/

Answer (score 0):

It seems as you have not set up your environment with java variables.
Try adding this to either your `~/.zshrc` or `~/.basrc`

```sh
export PATH={PATH_TO_JAVA_INSTALLATION}:$PATH
export JAVA_HOME={SAME_PATH_TO_JAVA_INSTALLATION}
```

Your Java Path is most likely in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/{some .jdk file}`